# How to set the limit of BoostCake pagination?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am working with [BoostCake](https://github.com/slywalker/cakephp-plugin-boost_cake) to use Twitter Bootstrap in my project in CakePHP, But I cant find the way to set the limit of pagination.

Anyone can give me a hint how to set up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set it up as you would normally, regardless of whether you are using BoostCake or not.

In your action:

```
$this->Paginator->settings = array(
    'limit' => 10
);
```

BoostCake is only meant to affect the views, not the controllers or other components.